# No response when sending a POST request using the Strawpoll API

Tags: java, json, rest, restlet

I am trying to create a Strawpoll using Restlet. Here's my code:

```
ClientResource resource = new ClientResource("https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls");

JSONObject body = new JSONObject();
JSONArray options = new JSONArray();
options.put("Option 1");
options.put("Option 2");

try {
     body.put("title", "Example Title");
     body.put("options", options);
     body.put("multi", false);
     body.put("captcha", true);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Representation bodyRepr = new StringRepresentation(body.toString());
bodyRepr.setMediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
try {
  System.out.println(resource.post(bodyRepr).getText());
} catch (ResourceException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately I'm not getting a response back. *getText()* only returns "null". I then tried to submit the following, equivalent request using Postman:

```
{
"captcha": true,
"options": ["Option 1", "Option 2"],
"title": "Example Title",
"multi": false
}
```

This time I get a proper response:

```
{
"id": 11187617,
"title": "Example Title",
"options": ["Option 1", "Option 2"],
"votes": [0, 0],
"multi": false,
"dupcheck": "normal",
"captcha": true
}
```

So I assume something is wrong with my Java code but I can't figure out what. Here's Strawpoll's API: https://github.com/strawpoll/strawpoll/wiki/API.